# Call function with signal on other scene

Tags: godot-4

I'm still getting confused as how to call a function from another script on another scene in Godot 4.x. In my example below, I want to call print_something() on menu.tscn from main.tscn

On main scene we have:

```
# main.gd
# main.tscn
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    print_something("Hello") #works on main

func print_something(astring):
    print(astring)
```

On menu scene we have:

```
# menu.gd
# menu.tscn
extends Node2D
signal mysignal
@export var message := "Gwen Stefani is bananas!"
# main.print_something(message) # Unexpected "Identifier" in class body.
```

When trying to connect the signal node I'm not given the option of picking another scene.
[image: connect signal node]

Undated script as Alex CB suggested still results in error:
extends Node2D

```
extends Node2D
# menu.tscn
@onready var main := get_tree().root.get_node("main")
@export var message := "Gwen Stefani is bananas!"
# then you can use
main.print_something(message)
```

[image: unexpected "Identifier" in class body]

Comment: I think you don't need a `signal` for this. The [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/best_practices/scene_organization.html) states that signals are best used to respond to behaviour, not to start it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to globally/uniquely reference a node in another scene?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/199691/is-there-a-way-to-globally-uniquely-reference-a-node-in-another-scene)

Comment: By the way, about `main.print_something(message)`, GDScript does not support top level statements. It would go inside some method.

Comment: You can't tell from the screenshot, but I'd forgotten to add the menu to the main node. Which naturally would complicate things...

Answer (score 1):

To connect a `signal` by code, you do like this:

```
var err := main.connect("signal_name", callable_name)
```

But, for what I understand you want to do, you don't need a `signal`.
According to the official [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/best_practices/scene_organization.html):

> (signals) should be used only to "respond" to behavior, not start it.
> By convention, signal names are usually past-tense verbs like
> "entered", "skill_activated", or "item_collected".

Another way could be to access `main` from the `menu`, like this:

```
@onready var main := get_tree().root.get_node("main")
# or, if menu is a direct child of main
@onready var main := get_parent()


@export var message := "Gwen Stefani is bananas!"
# then you can use inside a function 
func _ready():
  main.print_something(message)
```

Also, you'll have to instance `menu` scene in your `main` scene by clicking the `Instance child scene` (chain icon, top left, next to the `+` symbol).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the non-signal method (pun not intended), but am still getting unexpected "Identifier" in class body